# Visualforce page shows CSS errors for the same styling used by a html template

Tags: visualforce, static-resources

I downloaded a free html responsive template from the web and trying to convert it to a visualforce page. The page I am trying to reproduce is blank, so there is no content except css, js and nav bar.

I copy-pasted the content body to my new visualforce page and converted the css and js files to static resources which are used using the includeScript tag.

The issue is that the browser shows css errors for the bootstrap and style.css files for my visualforce page but it runs the html template smoothly. It shows that the errors are in the script files I am using.

If that was the case, wont the html template not render as well?

I am attaching the screenshots of my vf page and the template for comparison.

VF page:

[image]

Html template:

[image]

Comment: Have you set useStandardStylesheet as false?

Comment: No. I have not included that attribute in the page tag.

Comment: Try that.. It might be a standard Salesforce stykesheets messing with your responsive template

Comment: I did useStandardStylesheet="false", but it made no difference. The page is still blank as shown above, just the font is a little bigger now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this error when the stylesheet is inadvertently included with a `script` or `apex:includeScript` tag (**incorrect**):

```
<script src="css/style.css"></script>
<apex:includeScript value="css/style.css" />
```

...rather than a `link` or `apex:stylesheet` tag (**correct**):

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<apex:stylesheet value="css/style.css" />
```

See the official docs on [apex:includeScript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_includeScript.htm) and [apex:stylesheet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_stylesheet.htm) for more details.

Comment: I am using <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.css, 'css/style.css')}"/> instead of the script and link tags

Comment: Yep, `apex:includeScript` is for including Javascript scripts.  Use `apex:stylesheet` to include your stylesheet.  See [the official docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_stylesheet.htm) for more info.

Comment: I've updated my post.

Comment: This is super embarrassing. Thanks for the help. I forgot there was a stylesheet tag for css

Answer (score 0):

You can import the bootstrap zip in your Salesforce Organization as static resource and include the js and css files as below. Here are couple of links [link1](http://www.oyecode.com/2013/05/how-to-use-twitter-bootstrap-with.html) [link2](http://www.oyecode.com/2013/11/how-to-use-bootstrap-3-with.html), which describes the process in detail.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account"showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
         <link href="{!URLFOR($Resource.bootStrap, 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
         <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.bootstrap, 'js/bootstrap.min.js')}"/>

   <html>
      <head></head>
      <body>
        <!-- Your code -->
      </body>
   </html>
</apex:page>
```